# NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource

Tags: dapp-development, dapps, metamask

I'm getting this error in Firefox when running a dApp:

```
Error: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.
Stack trace:
InvalidResponse@http://localhost:8081/bundle.js line 995 > eval:38:16
RequestManager.prototype.sendAsync/<@http://localhost:8081/bundle.js line 7645 > eval:86:29
MetamaskInpageProvider/self.sendAsync/<@moz-extension://bb21b38e-ca5a-6847-afb3-0e13f721de3f/scripts/inpage.js:168:7
[136]</StreamProvider.prototype._onResponse/<@moz-extension://bb21b38e-ca5a-6847-afb3-0e13f721de3f/scripts/inpage.js:8222:5
```

Anyone seen this? If not - any ideas on how to debug it?

Comment: are you runing a local node?geth?

Comment: @BadrBellaj - yes - `testrpc`

Comment: Actually, I've just disabled `metamask` in `firefox`, and the error goes away and everything works perfectly. Hmmmm...

Comment: I have been getting the same error since yesterday using Metamask with Firefox across two computers. Did you find a fix?

Comment: @SamuelBarnes - no - I've posted [this issue](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/1779) on MetaMask...

Comment: ps. @SamuelBarnes, add your name to the issue posted on MetaMask, so that the developers know it aint just me ;)